# Why is my gui blank while a QThread is tunning

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qthread, pyqt6

PyQt6 py 3.11.5

whenever i run this specific gui application in a thread, it doesnt show anything until the thread quits. (i removed some functions that werent relevant but the problem still happens)

```
class TicTacToe(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_TicTacToe):
    
    def __init__(self, sym, sock, BUFF):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.thread = QThread(parent=self)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.recv)
        self.sock = sock
        self.BUFF = BUFF
        self.setWindowTitle('Tic Tac Toe')
        self.sym = sym
        self.buttons = []
        
        for i in range(9):
            button = self.findChild(QPushButton, f"pushButton_{i+1}")
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.button_click, button))
            self.buttons.append(button)
        self.actionExit_Game.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.sym_2 = 'O' if self.sym == 'X' else 'X'
        self.label.setText(f'Waiting for another player to join')
        
        self.waiting()
        
    def waiting(self):
        for i in self.buttons:
            i.setEnabled(False)

        self.thread.start()
        
        
    def recv(self):
        print('[CLIENT] waiting for message')
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)
        self.thread.quit()

    def button_click(self,b):
        pass


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication([])
        window = TicTacToe('X',None, None)
        window.show()
        app.exec()
```

[unresponding ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx3Tc.png)
ui file

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_TicTacToe(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(415, 500)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 391, 340))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setFont(font)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setText("")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_8.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_8.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setText("")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_1.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_1.setText("")
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setText("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_9.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_9.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setText("")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.gridLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(100)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setText("")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 391, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 415, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExit_Game = QtGui.QAction(parent=MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_Game.setObjectName("actionExit_Game")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit_Game)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "It is X\'s turn"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionExit_Game.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit Game"))
```

i tried removing everything in the function up to just having a QSleep, but the thread still has an effect on the main gui event loop

Comment: You're not running anything in the thread. `recv` is a member of `TicTacToe`, which "lives" in the main thread (see [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity)), so it will be run in that thread. If you want to execute something in an actual separate thread, you must use `moveToThread()` with a QObject subclass that implements the "working" function, or directly subclass QThread and override `run()`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, could you give me an example as to what you mean by subclassing QThread? i also have other classes in which i run pretty much the exact same code (running a class function inside a qthread) but they work.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by "running a class function inside a qthread", but **IF** you were actually able to execute an *instance method* on a thread different than it was created, then it means that you *explicitly* called that method from the other thread, which is **not** the same thing. Please read the link above and do some research using basic queries like "QThread", "PyQt" and "subclassing". Then, if after thorough studying you're still not able to understand it, please edit your question and provide some examples based on your attempts. Sorry, but this is not a tutorial website.